# Is NATO actually obsolete?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, nato

Recently Donald Trump said he thinks NATO is obsolete and needs to be remodeled. He claims that because the Soviet Union no longer exists there is no need to still have NATO. Is Donald Trump correct in saying that NATO is obsolete?

Comment: As stated, this question requires an Answer that exceeds the scope this mechanism can support.

Comment: No it is not obsolete: still it can Kill; but Donald Trump wants more powerful killing organization.

Comment: This is very much a matter of opinion. A good question to ask, but not here.

Comment: @PointlessSpike Let's just reinforce what the OP is attempting to find out.  Nearly the entirety of the European community attempted to enact a no-fly zone over the country of libya.  Which is extremely close by.  They failed and ran out of munitions.  The CaC and Logistical structure was pre-modern, at best.  The US took over shortly afterwards and things, once agin, ran smoothly.  NATO is almost entirely dependent upon US structure and support.